# PHP image path changes when I move to local server

Tags: php, apache, localhost, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a website that works fine when deployed on a remote development server. However, when I move it to my local machine, all the images paths' are now not pointed to the right directory.

Where as `<img src="/images/breadicon.png" />` used to work, I now get a 404 file not found.

When I update that to `<img src="./images/breadicon.png" />`, the image is found, but I don't want to have to revert back all my links when I re-deploy this site - and of course I don't want to have to work from the remote server.

The issue is, without the `.`, the path is perceived as `http://localhost/images/breadicon.png` instead of `http://localhost/sitename/images/breadicon.php`

What can I do to resolve all the links and have my links without ruining the code for redeployment?

Comment: It might be easier to set up your localhost configuration as local.sitename.com. You can do this using your hosts file and web server configuration. Otherwise your alternative is to put some kind of base path handling into all of your templates.

Comment: Your webserver most likely has a different root directory setup for this host. / = root ./ = from current directory

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is probably to set up a web host on your local machine.

For example, if your live/remote site was `http://www.example.com/`, you could set up a local web host as `http://example/`.

I'm assuming you're on Windows and using Apache. You'd need to edit your hosts file (using notepad, running as administrator, usually found here: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) to contain:

```
127.0.0.1 example
```

Then create an Apache host config file, for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example
DocumentRoot C:/Path/To/Site/example
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart Apache and go to `http://example/`. Assuming you follow a standard convention for links etc, this should do the trick.

Comment: Okay, after a restart of Apache, the index.php does load, but links are still broken. Browsing to http://example/ does work, however, something is definitely amiss. CSS and some images work, other images don't work, and none of the links work (using an .htaccess file for mod_rewrite rules).

Comment: It sounds like the image paths aren't consistent across the project. Could you post an example `<img src="..." />` that does work, and one that doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your webserver such that the site can be accessed under `http://localhost/` instead of `http://localhost/sitename`.

If that name is already used for a different purpose, create a virtual host named e.g. `sitename` in the webserver and edit your hosts file so that `sitename` points to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Yes, since I will be using the "htdocs" dir (localhost) to build multiple sites in the same manner. (Not actually htdocs, but `/Library/WebServer/Documents/` on Mac OS 10.8